# starting to on QThread stomped by the RLock

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4, pyside, qthread

Hi I do not have experience with PyQt threading, this is my first attempt to make my existing application multithreaded,

But I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/Development/python/slideShow/python/gallery.py", line 3, in <module>
    import utils
  File "~/Development/python/slideShow/python/utils.py", line 3, in <module>
    import exifread
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/exifread/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 206, in <module>
    _lock = threading.RLock()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RLock'
Exception AttributeError: '_shutdown' in <module 'threading' from '~/Development/python/slideShow/python/threading.pyc'> ignored
```

what I don't understand is when I haven't triggered the event that will execute the method initiating the gallery in different thread then how come this error shows up at the time I run the main application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have named a module in your project `threading` (`~/Development/python/slideShow/python/threading.py`). This will shadow python's [`threading`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading) module, which the `logging` module tries to access.

Just rename your module to something else. It's always a bad idea to choose module names that conflicht with python's standard library modules.